# How to test regexes validation through RSPEC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

This is the Consumer class with validations

```
class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create, message: 'invalid email format'}, length: { maximum: 256 }
```

This is what I used to test whether a consumer's email is in the valid format or not but I am getting errors. Is there a better way to test regexes other than this method?

```
it 'email with invalid format is invalid' do
consumer = Consumer.new(email: 'bugs', password: '12345')
consumer.valid?
consumer.errors.full_messages
expect(consumer.errors.get(:email)).to eq(['email is not valid'])
 end


it 'has no errors for valid email format' do
consumer = Consumer.new(email: 'bugs@disney.com', password: '12345')
consumer.valid?
consumer.errors.full_messages
expect(consumer.errors.get(:email)).to be_nil
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your test if you guarantee that all other values of your `Consumer` object are valid.

For example, lets say your `Customer` has `email`, `password`, `name`, `last_name`; then you can test this way:

```
it 'email with invalid format is invalid' do
  consumer = Consumer.new(email: 'bugs', password: '12345', name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe')
  expect(consumer.valid?).to be(false)
end
```

In this example all attributes are correct, except `email`, so just checking if `valid?` returns `false` will be enough.